how to tell VS Code to automatically choose the interpreter specified at the root on the project
I already have script in my .zshrc that automatically activate the conda environement when I'm entering a directory having an environement.yml file.
the file is created as follow:
conda activate my-useful-env
conda env export > environment.yml

which contains
name: my-useful-env
channels:
 - nodefaults
 - conda-forge
 - defaults
dependencies:
 - _libgcc_mutex=0.1=conda_forge
 - _openmp_mutex=4.5=2_gnu
 - bzip2=1.0.8=hd590300_5
 - ca-certificates=2024.6.2=hbcca054_0
 [...]
prefix: /home/myusername/miniconda3/envs/accounting

I'd like find a way to tell VS Code to automatically set the interpreter specified in that file when it's present at the root of the workspace.
any ideas?
